# Is it considered safe to manually edit schema.rb in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, schema, database-migration

I came across a problem where I was working on two branches on a rails project and each project has a migration to add a column. At the time, `rake db:migrate:reset` cause a problem and I solely relied on my `schema.rb` to correctly represent the state of my database. At one point, I came across a problem where a column added by branch A got into the schema of branch B. Since `migrate:reset` was not an option, I resorted to manually editing the schema file to. I committed this change that basically deleted the column from branch A that I did not need in branch B's schema.rb.

Problem came after I have merged branch A into master. When I tried to rebase branch B to master, I still had that commit in B to delete the column (which now has become relevant because it is in master) in the schema file. Git did not see a conflict for this and auto-merged it. At the end of my rebase, I found that my schema is inconsistent with what I have in master.

My fix is to edit the schema file again and manually add the previously deleted column back to the schema file. My question is: Is this considered unconventional? dangerous? hacky?

Right now it involves one column but if this involved multiple column deletions/additions the (dangerous?) solution could lead to more problems and db/schema.rb inconsistency.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is generally considered a bad practice to edit your `schema.rb` file.

According to the [Rails Guide on Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html):

> Migrations, mighty as they may be, are not the authoritative source for your database schema. That role falls to either db/schema.rb or an SQL file which Active Record generates by examining the database. They are not designed to be edited, they just represent the current state of the database.

`schema.rb` gets updated *every time you run a new migration*:

> Note that running the db:migrate also invokes the db:schema:dump task, which will update your db/schema.rb file to match the structure of your database.

I'd recommend just spending some time to sort things out and get the `schema.rb` file back on track and correct up to the latest set of migrations.

Comment: Agreed.  You're potentially hosing up the utility of "rake db:migrate version=xxx" and creating future headaches by going off the reservation and manually editing schema.rb.