# Generate rails db migrations files from active database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

Is there any way to take a running database and generate a migration file from it?  If not does anyone have any advice on how to approach that?

Background: Have a new project where a PHP developer jumped into a rails project and starting adding tables and columns though PostGres admin tool.

Comment: you mean you want to reverse the added columns from the table. essentially remove the added migrations?

Comment: Generate a schema of the running database.  I think i may have found rake -T db:schema:dump

Comment: You could just manually add the tables and columns to your schema.rb file.

Comment: yeah, try that rake command. usually, you shouldn't touch the schema file. the fields should populate once you run the migration

Comment: True, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301009/is-it-considered-safe-to-manually-edit-schema-rb-in-rails
That answer also suggests db:schema:dump task, which will update your db/schema.rb file to match the structure of your database.

Comment: I created a Log directory and then was able to run the command, i'll answer the question with this in case anyone else runs into it

Answer (score 2):

Created a directory called "log" then ran this command

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:schema:dump
```